# Inserting data into a non-organized table in word from SMO file

Tags: python, smo

Relatively new to programming, ive been banging my head against a wall now for several day (on my own time)

I need to export data from a list that ive collected through a sliced text and a collect numbers function. Ive come a long way by identifing tables in a word document, and completing this import/export process for other tables. However, the table I am trying to send data to this time is not well-built. (snippet included below).

Furthermore, in word it is a "frozen" heading. meaning it repeats itself at the following page. (its a designed template for work, friggin nightmare).

So theres 3 problems I need to solve.

1. alternating goal columns (second/third)
2. merged rows
3. repeating headings.

Id love some advice on this. Not one for giving up, but its getting there.

[Goal table (copied from word to excel for ease of interpretation, goal entry being the column of which I want to enter my list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeJan.png)

```
# Open the existing Document object
doc = Document(Word_file)


# Find the '{Størrelser}' table
table_title = '{Størrelser}'
table = None
for tbl in doc.tables:
    if tbl.cell(0, 0).text.strip() == table_title:
        table = tbl
        break


## Add the values to the specific cell
for i, value in enumerate(Kontrollskjema):  # start=0 by default e
    # Calculate row index, +1 to start from the second row
    row_idx = i + 1
    # Set column index to 2 for the third column for rows 2,3,4,5 and 8,9,10,11
    # Else set it to 1 for the second column
    col_idx = 2 if row_idx in [2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11] else 1

    # Check if the row exists
    if row_idx < len(table.rows):
        # Check if the row has the required column
        if len(table.rows[row_idx].cells) > col_idx:
            cell = table.cell(row_idx, col_idx)  # cell(row_idx, col_idx), 0-indexed
            cell.text = str(value)
            paragraph = cell.paragraphs[0]
            run = paragraph.runs[0]
            run.font.name = 'Avenir Next LT Pro'
            run.font.size = Pt(10)
            paragraph.alignment = WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.LEFT
        else: 
            print(f"Row {row_idx + 1} does not have a column {col_idx + 1}.")
    else:
        print(f"Row {row_idx + 1} does not exist.")


print(f"the length of the variable Kontrollskjema is {len(Kontrollskjema)}")

print(Kontrollskjema)

def print_rows_per_column(table):
    # Initialize a list to hold the count of rows for each column
    column_counts = []

    # Iterate over the rows of the table
    for row in table.rows:
        # Count the number of cells (columns) in the row
        column_count = len(row.cells)
        # If the list of column counts is not long enough, extend it
        while len(column_counts) < column_count:
            column_counts.append(0)
        # Increment the count for each column in the row
        for i in range(column_count):
            column_counts[i] += 1

    # Print the number of rows for each column
    for i, count in enumerate(column_counts, start=1):
        print(f"The number of rows in column {i} is {count}")

# Usage
print_rows_per_column(table)




#Output

# 26
Row 30 does not have a column 2.
Row 31 does not have a column 2.
Row 32 does not have a column 2.
Row 33 does not have a column 2.
Row 34 does not have a column 2.
Row 35 does not exist.
Row 36 does not exist.
the length of the variable Kontrollskjema is 35
[353, 135, 141, 16, 566, 1396, 0.19, 0.93, 0.2, 0.8, 0.06, 2.8, 0.06, 417, 9.0, 19, 2.5, 1.7, 0.0, 0.81, 25, 20.3, 0.0, 'Oppvarming 16/7/52\n', 'Oppvarming 16/7/52\nKjøling 24/7/52\nVentilasjon 24/7/52\nBelysning 16/7/52\nUtsyr 16/7/52\nPersoner 24/7/52\n', 1.95, 1.95, 3.0, 1.8, 3.4, 0.0, 1.5, 0.55, 0.2, '0.74/1.0/0.84/0.78']
The number of rows in column 1 is 29
The number of rows in column 2 is 29
The number of rows in column 3 is 28
The number of rows in column 4 is 28
The number of rows in column 5 is 28
The number of rows in column 6 is 28
```